# git add -p で y などの入力が効かなくなる

Tags: git, zsh, iterm

iterm2 と zsh を使っています。

`git add -p` したときに、入力を受付なくなることが稀によくあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

itermを再起動したり、タブを新しく開いたりすると、そのタブでは入力できるようになります。

なぜこのようになるのでしょうか？また、どうしたら回避できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

原因については解りませんが、
<kbd>Enter</kbd> が効かなくなった時のとりあえずの回避策として、<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> が代わりに使えると思います。